# Proof of Binomial Identity using hypergeometric function

Tags: binomial-coefficients, hypergeometric-function

$$
\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} {{n\choose k}    (-1)^k \frac{\theta}{\theta + k}}    =    \prod\limits_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{k}{\theta + k}}, \mbox{        for all } \theta > 0 \mbox{ and all } n \in \mathbb{N}$$

Could someone please show how to prove this binomial identity evaluating the left side of the equation as the evaluation of a hypergeometric function $_2F_1(-n,\theta ;\theta +1|1)$ and then applying the Chu-Vandermonde formula to get the right side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from the definition of the hypergeometric function from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_hypergeometric_theorem)
$$_2F_1(a,b;c;z) = \sum_{m\ge 0} \frac{(a)_m (b)_m}{(c)_m} \frac{z^m}{m!}$$
with $(q)_n$ the rising Pochhammer symbol, we see that
$$_2F_1(-n,\theta;\theta+1; 1) =
\sum_{m\ge 0} \frac{(-n)_m (\theta)_m}{(\theta+1)_m} \frac{1}{m!} =
\sum_{m=0}^n \frac{(-n)_m (\theta)_m}{(\theta+1)_m} \frac{1}{m!}$$
because when $m>n$ there is a zero term in $(-n)_m.$ 
Continuing
$$ \sum_{m= 0}^n (-1)^m \frac{n!}{(n-m)!} \frac{(\theta)_m}{(\theta+1)_m} \frac{1}{m!}
 = \sum_{m= 0}^n (-1)^m \binom{n}{m} \frac{\theta}{\theta+m}.$$
This is the left side.

For the right side, according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde's_identity) and [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Chu-VandermondeIdentity.html) we have that
$$_2F_1(a,b;c;1) = \frac{\Gamma(c)\Gamma(c-a-b)}{\Gamma(c-a)\Gamma(c-b)}.$$
This gives
$$_2F_1(-n,\theta;\theta+1; 1) =
 \frac{\Gamma(\theta+1)\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(\theta+1+n)\Gamma(1)}
= n! \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\theta + k} =
\prod_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{\theta + k}.$$

**Addendum.** A proof by induction of this identity can be found at the following [MSE Post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477174/a-convergent-series). There is another proof by Mellin transforms at this [MSE Post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/485715/prove-sum-n-infty-prod-k-0n-dfrac1xk-e-sum-n-infty-dfrac).