# How find this sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)\cdots(n+2014)}$

Tags: summation

Find the sum
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)\cdots(n+2014)}$$

My idea: since
$$\dfrac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(n+2014)}=\dfrac{1}{2014}\left(\dfrac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(n+2013)}-\dfrac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(n+2014)}\right)?$$

Comment: Where is this problem from? what have you tried?

Comment: Taking logarithm and then integral...doesn't that help?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477174/a-convergent-series

Comment: Your idea should work, giving a telescoping series. Sneaky!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

The telescoping sum is useful
$$\dfrac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)\cdots(n+2014)}=\frac1{2014}\dfrac{(n+2014)-n}{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)\cdots(n+2014)}=\frac 1{2014}\left(\dfrac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)\cdots(n+2013)}-\dfrac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)\cdots(n+2014)}\right)$$

Comment: After this? Isn't this a deadlock?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Then maybe I cannot see it.

Comment: @Hawk: See [the Wikipedia article on telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Telescoping_series&oldid=594349475), which introduces an example very similar to this one.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Ah yes, I just noticed that it has a summation symbol, I was thinking it to be a limit symbol.

Comment: Excellent, Sami!

Answer (score 0):

Just by curiosity, I used a CAS for the computation of $$S(m)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)\cdots(n+m)}$$ The first result was quite amazing $$S(m)=\frac{\Gamma (m) \Gamma (m+2)}{(2)_m \Gamma (m+1)^2}$$ where appear Pochhammer numbers. Fortunately, this simplifies to $$S(m)=\frac{1}{m^2 \Gamma (m)}$$ which is a quite nice closed form.