# I need help to evaluate $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\prod_{j=0}^p(k+j)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, products

I need help to evaluate the following sum: $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\prod_{j=0}^p(k+j)}.$$

I wrote it in terms of Gamma functions to eliminate the product: $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma(k)}{\Gamma(p+k+1)}$.
I'm not sure what to do from here.

Comment: (Also [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/477174)... seems like :[|||||]: pretty old)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the fraction looks almost like [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) it was worth to *complete* it. So we have $$\begin{split}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma(k)}{\Gamma(p+k+1)}  & = \frac{1}{\Gamma(p+1)}\times \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma(k)\Gamma(p+1)}{\Gamma(p+k+1)} \\
 & = \frac{1}{\Gamma(p+1)}\times \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathrm{B}(p+1,k)\\
 & = \frac{1}{\Gamma(p+1)}\times \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1} \xi^{k-1}(1-\xi)^{p}\,\mathrm{d}\xi\\
 & = \frac{1}{\Gamma(p+1)}\times \int_{0}^{1} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\xi^{k-1}(1-\xi)^{p}\,\mathrm{d}\xi\\
 & = \frac{1}{\Gamma(p+1)}\times \int_{0}^{1} (1-\xi)^{p-1}\,\mathrm{d}\xi\\  
&= \frac{1}{\Gamma(p+1)}\times \frac{1}{p} \ . 
\end{split}$$ If you do not like Beta function you might try do this by *partial-ish fraction decomposition* and telescoping since $$\frac{1}{k(k+1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(k+p)}=\frac{1}{p}\left(\eta_{k,p}-\eta_{k+1,p}\right),$$
where $\eta_{k,p}=\frac{1}{k(k+1)\cdot\ldots\cdot (k+p-1)}$.

Answer (score 1):

It is well known that both
$\dfrac1{\prod_{j=0}^n(k+j)}
$
and
$\prod_{j=0}^n(k+j)$
have a decomposition that
results in their sums telescoping.

Let
$p_n(k)
=\prod_{j=0}^n(k+j)
$.
Then

$\begin{array}\\
p_n(k+1)-p_n(k)
&=\prod_{j=0}^n(k+1+j)-\prod_{j=0}^n(k+j)\\
&=\prod_{j=1}^{n+1}(k+j)-\prod_{j=0}^n(k+j)\\
&=\prod_{j=1}^{n}(k+j)((n+k+1)-k)\\
&=\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}(k+1+j)(n+1)\\
&=(n+1)p_{n-1}(k+1)\\
\end{array}
$

so
$p_n(k)
=\dfrac{p_{n+1}(k)-p_{n+1}(k-1)}{n+2}
$.

Similarly,

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac1{p_n(k)}-\dfrac1{p_n(k+1)}
&=\dfrac1{\prod_{j=0}^n(k+j)}-\dfrac1{\prod_{j=0}^n(k+1+j)}\\
&=\dfrac1{\prod_{j=0}^n(k+j)}-\dfrac1{\prod_{j=1}^{n+1}(k+j)}\\
&=\dfrac1{\prod_{j=0}^{n+1}(k+j)}((n+1+k)-k)\\
&=p_{n+1}(k)(n+1)\\
\end{array}
$

so
$p_n(k)
=\dfrac1{n}(\dfrac1{p_{n-1}(k)}-\dfrac1{p_{n-1}(k+1)})
$.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to consider the partial sum$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\Gamma(k)}{\Gamma(p+k+1)}$$ and prove that
$$S_n=\frac{(p+1) \Gamma (n+p+2)-(n+p+1) \Gamma (n+1) \Gamma (p+2)}{p \Gamma (p+2) \Gamma
   (n+p+2)}$$ which, once simplified is just
$$S_n=\frac{1}{p \,\Gamma (p+1)}-\frac{\Gamma (n+1)}{p\, \Gamma (n+p+1)}$$ Now, using Stirling approximation twice and continuing with Taylor series for large values of $n$

$$A=\log\Bigg[\frac{\Gamma (n+1)}{p\, \Gamma (n+p+1)}\Bigg]=-(p \log (n)+\log (p))-\frac{p (p+1)}{2 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$
$$\frac{\Gamma (n+1)}{p\, \Gamma (n+p+1)}=e^A=n^{-p} \left(\frac{1}{p}-\frac{p+1}{2 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)$$ So, as a first approximation
$$S_n=\frac{1}{p \,\Gamma (p+1)}-n^{-p} \left(\frac{1}{p}-\frac{p+1}{2 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)$$